# Representation of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, signal-processing, duality-theorems

NOTE : This Question is migrated from here : [Electrical Engineering stackexchange Question link][1]

I have a problem interpreting 2 different representations of Fourier transform and proving their property.
In some texts Fourier transform is represented as:

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(j\omega)e^{j\omega t}\,d\omega} \\
X(j\omega) = & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt
\end{align*}
$$

While in other texts the complex number $j$ is omitted in $X(j\omega)$. The problem comes when we try to prove things where the two notations don't work likely; for example, $\frac{d}{d\omega}X(j\omega) = jX'(j\omega)$, and $\frac{d}{d\omega}X(\omega) = X'(\omega)$.

I faced this confusion while proving the Duality property of Fourier transform; namely:

$$
\text{if}\;\mathcal{F}[x(t)] = X(j\omega),\;\; \text{then}\; \mathcal{F}[X(t)] = 2\pi\,x(-j\omega)\,
$$

in one representation and

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) & \leftrightarrow X(j\omega) \\
X(t) & \leftrightarrow 2\pi\ x(-\omega)
\end{align*}
$$

in other representation.

I believe that in duality result of the former representation $X(j\omega)$ should contain additional $j$, i.e. $X(t)\rightarrow 2\pi jx(-j\omega)$, when i tried to prove it. But now I am confused.

Here is my proof, can someone validate that this is correct or correct it?
Notice the extra $j$ I am getting.

### Proof

$$
x(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(j\Omega)e^{j\Omega t}\,d\Omega}
$$

Replace $t$ with $-j\omega$, and $j\Omega$ with $t$ (just a change of variables),

$$
\begin{align*}
\Longrightarrow\; & 2\pi x(-j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}X(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,d(t/j)\,, \\
\Longrightarrow\; & 2\pi jw(-j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}X(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt\,,
\end{align*}
$$

So, I can say that $\mathcal{F}\{X(t)\} = 2\pi jx(-j\omega)$. END

---

Lot of articles or tutorials on google search uses this $X(\omega)$ notation instead of $X(j\omega)$.

I have found $X(j\omega)$ notation intuitive lot of times. Can some one please explain?

Comment: $X(j\omega)$ is the Laplace transform notation.

Comment: @reuns I got your point, but both notations are representing same thing, how should I interpret duality property, with these different notations as results are different.